# Same Firebase Instance for iOS and Android app

Tags: android, ios, firebase

I am new to android, but I have finished setting up a Firebase backend for an iOS application. Now I am starting to code the Android version which should access the same Firebase backend.

My question is this... do I need to create a new Firebase instance for the Android backend!? I was hopeful to use the same Firebase instance that I have created for the iOS application?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are building an android version of the app you use the same firebase project however when you are in the console you **click Overview -> 'Add Another App' -> Click 'Android'**

Follow the android setup and you are all good.

Comment: How to work with different googleservice-info.plist files for Android and iOS?

Comment: Whenever I complete the IOS SDK setup it removes the Android setup. Then when I complete the Android setup again it removes the IOS setup. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4):

You **can** and you **should** use Same Firebase Project. So that, the database will be share between iOS and Android app.

Answer (score 3):

While in your **Project Overview** click the **cog Wheel** and select **project settings**, while in **settings** under the **general** tab scroll down to **Your apps** and click **Add App**. then add another environment you want.