# How to get Firebase Android and Firebase IOS to talk to each other

Tags: android, ios, firebase

I have just finished the Android side of my application which is through Firebase, as well as, I have the same application but with iOS Firebase.  How do I get both the Android and iOS Firebase to talk to each other?

What I mean is, it is a ride-sharing app, so if a user is using Android but the driver is on iOS, how do I get firebase to be using the same database, same info?

Comment: What are you talking about?  There is no iOS Firebase vs Android Firebase.  It's just Firebase (with iOS client, Web Client, Andorid Client, etc...).  Wait, did you create two separate projects in the Firebase Console instead of just adding the iOS and Android apps to the same project?

Comment: yes, when I created the iOS App, I created an iOS app in Firebase, then when I created the Android app, I created an Android project in Firebase ...

Comment: Select either project. Pick just one.  Follow [these directions](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592) to download the Google-Services file for both Android and iOS (click add app for missing platform).  Make sure both apps use the plist/json settings for the same project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably You should control, with a method, the user information. 
For android : control the iOS database and verify that the user information don't exist, and if exist, copy that. Viceversa for iOS.

The other option is to use the same Firebase Project for each app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Riccardo Fassina, can you provide an example of such method or how I can use the same Firebase Project for each type (iOS, android)?  The only other problem is with Android, I am using an app for the Rider, and an app for the Driver but with iOS I am using one app for both the Rider/Driver.

Comment: Usually u can create two different project (android and iOS) with the same Firebase project inside the console. Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42731422/same-firebase-instance-for-ios-and-android-app

Comment: great, I will give this a look :)

Comment: This is the configure file for the same firebase project in iOS and Android : https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/